# Inserting multiple records in a plugin

Tags: plugin-development, database, services

I'm building a plugin and have a form in the plugin's CP page that allows admins to save access codes. The form is a simple `textarea` where each line is a separate access code.

I'm wondering what the best practice is in terms of inserting these records into the database?

**Controller:**

```
// This returns an array of codes to be inserted
$codes = explode("\r\n", craft()->request->getPost('codes'));

foreach($codes as $code) {
    $codeModel = new Portal_CodeModel();
    $codeModel->code = $code;
    $codeModels[] = $codeModel;
}

$success = craft()->portal_code->addCodes($codeModels);
```

**Service:**

```
public function addCodes($codes) {

    foreach($codes as $code) {

      Portal_CodeRecord::model()->insert(array(
          'code'        => $code,
          'code_used'   => 0
      ));

    }

}
```

**Record:**

```
class Portal_CodeRecord extends BaseRecord {

    public function getTableName() {
        return 'portal_codes';
    }

    protected function defineAttributes() {
        return array(
            'code'          => AttributeType::String,
            'code_used'     => AttributeType::Bool
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I know there are probably several issues with the above code. If there are any good examples on how to insert multiple records that'd be a huge help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go with #1.  It looks like you've already got a `Portal_CodeModel` created, you just need to populate them from the controller, perform validation (if any), then pass the array of `Portal_CodeModel` objects to your service.

You'll want to remove the `Portal_CodeModel` type hint from your service's `addCodes` signature (or change it to `array`) since you're passing in an array of objects, instead of a single one.

Here's an example in your controller with any code validation:

```
$codeModels = array();
$codes = explode("\r\n", craft()->request->getPost('codes'));

$success = craft()->portal_code->addCodes($codes);
```

And in your service:

```
public function addCodes($codes)
{

    foreach($codes as $code)
    {
        $existingCode = Portal_CodeRecord::model()->findByAttributes(array(
            'code' => $code,
        ));

        if ($existingCode)
        {
            $existingCode->code_used = 1;
            $existingCode->save();

            {# or whatever else you want to do when the code already exists in the database #}
        }
        else
        {
            $codeRecord = new Portal_CodeRecord();
            $codeRecord->code = $code;
            $codeRecord->code_used = 0;
            $codeRecord->save();
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: I get the following error with this setup:  `The active record cannot be inserted to database because it is not new.`

Comment: You'll have to share the actual PHP service code you're using when you get that error, but most likely you're calling `insert` on a code that already exists in the database when you should be calling `update`.

Comment: I updated the question based on comments.

Comment: From all the examples I've seen it shows the instance being created in the service, and then using `instanceName->save();`

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: My db table is empty so there's no chance of the record already existing. Running just the `insert()` portion of your above code should work. The error I still get is `The active record cannot be inserted to database because it is not new.`

Comment: Updated again...

Comment: Close. We were passing in an array of models. I updated the answer to make it correct.